# If F is a cumulative distribution function, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$

Tags: statistics

Let $F$ be a c.d.f for a random variable X and let
$$x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n<x_{n+1}<\cdots$$
be a monotonic increasing sequence that converges to $+\infty$. I've managed to do a tight proof of the fact that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F(x_n)=1$$
But now I am a bit worried that this implies that $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$. Here is my attempt at proving this second fact. Suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)\ne1$. Then there exists an $\epsilon_0$ such that:

1. There exists an $x_1^*>1$ so that $|F(x_1^*)-1|\ge \epsilon_0$
2. There exists an $x_2^*>\text{max}\{x_1^*,2\}$ so that $|F(x_2^*)-1|\ge \epsilon_0$
3. There exists an $x_3^*>\text{max}\{x_2^*,3\}$ so that $|F(x_3^*)-1|\ge \epsilon_0$
4. Etc, etc, etc, ...

Thus, I've created a sequence
$$x_1^*<x_2^*<\cdots<x_n^*<x_{n+1}^*<\cdots$$
that converges to $+\infty$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}F(x_n^*)\ne 1$, which contradicts my first proof. Hence, $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$.

Does this look like a valid proof to folks?

Comment: You probably should have replaced $1$ with $\epsilon$ on the right side of those inequality. This proof work, though kinda overcomplicated.

Comment: Agree, making a correction.

Answer (score 2):

Since $F(x)$ is by definition a non-decreasing function and $F(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$, $\lim_{ x \to \infty} F(x)$  must exist. Therefore, if you showed that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(x_n) = 1$ for some sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \to \infty$, it must be the case that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$.